# Creating Property Get/Let procedures for a private array

Tags: arrays, vba, properties

I am trying to assign a number of values to a private array in a class module using public Property Get/Let procedures. But when I try to get the values out, the array is showing as empty. Why is this?

Here's the relevant code:

```
Private pdt_RentStepDate(23) As Date

Public Property Get dt_RentStepDate(ByRef d1 As Integer) As Date
    dt_RentStepDate(d1) = pdt_RentStepDate(d1)
End Property

Public Property Let dt_RentStepDate(ByRef d1 As Integer, something As Date)
    pdt_RentStepDate(d1) = something
End Property
```

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` in your code? I wonder because I see both a `pd_RentStepRate` and a `pdt_RentStepDate` variable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: BTW, that's also why it's "hopping over to the Let." You've told your get to look at the Let, not at your private module-level variable.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you've updated the question based on my comment in my now-deleted answer. Your property definitions now look reasonable to me. The next question is how you are calling the class and properties. You'll need to show that code to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Property Get procedure, don't specify an index when you're assigning the return value:

```
Public Property Get dt_RentStepDate(ByRef d1 As Integer) As Date
'   dt_RentStepDate(d1) = pdt_RentStepDate(d1)  ' <-- WRONG
    dt_RentStepDate = pdt_RentStepDate(d1)      ' <-- RIGHT
End Property
```

If you specify an index, then instead of assigning the return value for the Property Get, you're actually calling the Property Let with the arguments `d1` and  `pdt_RentStepDate(d1)`. (This has no effect because the Property Let ends up setting `pdt_RentStepDate(d1)` to itself.) Since no return value is assigned, the Property Get always returns an empty Date.